System.IO.FileLoadException on Ubuntu 24.04 while running .Net 8 webapp or blazorapp
I am trying to host webapp/blazorapp (no matter at this point, apps themselves are just the templates ones from VS) on a ubuntu24.04 (at this point on raspberrypi5). I have clear installation of ubuntu with all necessary updates and upgrades then as per microsoft

sudo apt-get update && 
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-8.0

All dependencies are there, at this point I do not even care about hosting it with apache I just want to successfully run it, as a matter of fact I can WITHOUT any problems run console or api applications.
I have my directory (as this is dev env)

sudo chmod -R 777 /my/path/to/publish

and when

dotnet BlazorApp.dll

I got the following

Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'BlazorApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
Aborted (core dumped)

I will explain beforehand that I have set the ulimit -c to unlimited and all I get in the file is some utter nonesense random char spitout.
Have anyone stumbled on similar problem and resolved it?

assembly binding errors can be debugged using the .net FusionLog feature. quick websearch for "ubuntu fusionlog" shows that it is also available under linux. I also found a related question on SO at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555973/ , but without an accepted answer.

Where is the dll stored, and which directory are you in when you execute the dotnet command?

directory is var/www/test

while running self-contained application:
Failed to load /var/www/test/libhostpolicy.so, error: /var/www/test/libhostpolicy.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
An error occurred while loading required library libhostpolicy.so from [/var/www/test/]
it goes without saying that the file is there...

after many releases I've used "publish" gui, and noticed that there is another option of runtime to use, instead of using something like:

dotnet publish -c Release -o /var/www/ --runtime linux-x64

there is an option:

--runtime linux-arm64

it does make sense, as I have been trying to launch it on rpi5, however it did run api and console app flawlessly, but as exception suggest it didn't had to use System.IO which I imagine is completely different in arm.
Anywho, it did cost me couple of hours digging. Hope that'll help someone else...
